# Get first two lines from a file put it into hasmap as key and whole file as value of hashmap.And write hashmap to a file

Tags: java

Now consider two input files

**1.post_tran.tbl**(edited table)

```
[name]post_tran_id[/name]=[data] 1[/data]
[name]tran_nr[/name]=[data]2[/data]
[name]datetime_tran_local[/name]=[data]2002-04-02 19:02:28[/data]
[name]system_trace_audit_nr[/name]=[data]008497[/data]
[name]settle_amount_rsp[/name]=[data]4120[/data]
[name]settle_tran_fee_rsp[/name]=[data]10[/data]
[name]post_tran_cust_id[/name]=[data] 2[/data]
[name]prev_post_tran_id[/name]=[data] 0[/data]
[name]next_post_tran_id[/name]=[data]0[/data]
[name]message_type[/name]=[data]0200[/data]

[name]post_tran_id[/name]=[data] 2[/data]
[name]tran_nr[/name]=[data]2[/data]
[name]datetime_tran_local[/name]=[data]2002-04-02 19:02:28[/data]
[name]system_trace_audit_nr[/name]=[data]008497[/data]
[name]settle_amount_rsp[/name]=[data]4120[/data]
[name]settle_tran_fee_rsp[/name]=[data]10[/data]
[name]post_tran_cust_id[/name]=[data] 2[/data]
[name]prev_post_tran_id[/name]=[data] 0[/data]
[name]next_post_tran_id[/name]=[data]0[/data]
[name]message_type[/name]=[data]0200[/data]
```

**2.post_tran_cust.tbl**

```
[name]post_tran_cust_id[/name]=[data]1[/data]
[name]source_node_name[/name]=[data]TestSrc[/data]
[name]draft_capture[/name]=[data]0[/data]
[name]pan[/name]=[data]5892790010003952[/data]
[name]card_seq_nr[/name]=[data]NULL[/data]
[name]expiry_date[/name]=[data]0415[/data]

[name]post_tran_cust_id[/name]=[data]2[/data]
[name]source_node_name[/name]=[data]SrcDec[/data]
[name]draft_capture[/name]=[data]1[/data]
[name]pan[/name]=[data]5892790010003952[/data]
[name]card_seq_nr[/name]=[data]890[/data]
[name]expiry_date[/name]=[data]0816[/data]
```

These are the sample files which i need to process.below is the sample code.The code contains 2 hashmaps.
One hashmap is for post_tran.tbl which contains data values of first 2 rows as keys for hashmap and value is the corresponding whole record with first two rows. Second hashmap is for post_tran_cust which contains data value of first row as key for hashmap and value is corresponding whole record with first row.
Now I want to compare keys(for first hashmap i need only post_tran_cust_id)
on both hashmaps i.e post_tran_cust_id from hashmap1 and post_tran_cust_id
from hasmp2. If there exists a match then the corresponding records from 
both hashmaps are to be written into file.Kindly help me out.
Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Migrator {
void migrate(String post_tran, String post_tran_cust) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> h1 = loadFile(post_tran, KEY1);
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> h2 = loadFile(post_tran_cust, 
KEY2);

        // System.out.println("Hash Post_Tran................\n: " + h1);
        // System.out.println("Hash Post_Tran_Cust................\n: " + 
h2);

        PrintStream out = new 
PrintStream("D:\\Postcard_workspace_new\\Final\\final.tbl");
        // PrintStream out = System.out; // Used during testing

        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : h1.entrySet()) {
            Map<String, String> data = entry.getValue();
            if (h2.containsKey(data.get(KEY2))) {
                print(out, KEY1, data.get(KEY1));
                print(out, KEY2, data.get(KEY2));
                // Print remaining rows in any order
                for (String key : data.keySet()) {
                    if ( ! key.equals(KEY1) && ! key.equals(KEY2) ) {
                        print(out, key, data.get(key));
                    }
                }
                data = h2.get(data.get(KEY2));
                for (String key : data.keySet()) {
                    if ( ! key.equals(KEY2) ) {
                        print(out, key, data.get(key));
                    }
                }
                out.println(); // Record separator
            }
        }
    }

private Map<String, Map<String, String>> loadFile(String fileName, String 
key) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new HashMap<String, 
Map<String, String>>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;

        do {
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                data.put(getKey(line), getData(line));
            }

            result.put(data.get(key), data);
        } while (line != null);

        br.close();

        return result;
    }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Migrator mg = new Migrator();

      mg.migrate("post_tran.tbl","post_tran_cust.tbl");
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following assumes that empty lines are really empty, i.e. no spaces and such, and that there are no empty lines in the beginning.

Since I now understand a little bit more what it is you're trying to do, I have re-made a lot of the logic in this update.

No specific error handling to make it simpler.

```
public class Migrator {
    private static final String KEY1 = "post_tran_id";
    private static final String KEY2 = "post_tran_cust_id";

    void migrate(String post_tran, String post_tran_cust) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> h1 = loadFile(post_tran, KEY1);
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> h2 = loadFile(post_tran_cust, KEY2);

        PrintStream out = new PrintStream("final.tbl");

        for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : h1.entrySet()) {
            Map<String, String> data = entry.getValue();
            String k = data.get(KEY2);
            if (k != null && h2.containsKey(k.trim())) {
                print(out, KEY1, data.get(KEY1));
                print(out, KEY2, data.get(KEY2));
                // Print remaining rows in any order
                for (String key : data.keySet()) {
                    if ( ! key.equals(KEY1) && ! key.equals(KEY2) ) {
                        print(out, key, data.get(key));
                    }
                }
                data = h2.get(k.trim());
                for (String key : data.keySet()) {
                    if ( ! key.equals(KEY2) ) {
                        print(out, key, data.get(key));
                    }
                }
                out.println(); // Record separator
            }
        }
    }

    private void print(PrintStream out, String key, String data) {
        out.print("[name]");
        out.print(key);
        out.print("[/name]");
        out.print("=");
        out.print("[data]");
        out.print(data);
        out.print("[/data]");
        out.println();
    }

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> loadFile(String fileName, String key) throws IOException {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;

        do {
            Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
                data.put(getKey(line), getData(line));
            }

            result.put(data.get(key).trim(), data);
        } while (line != null);

        br.close();

        return result;
    }

    private String getKey(String line) {
        String[] tokens = line.split("=");
        int length = tokens[0].length();
        return tokens[0].substring(6, length - 7);
    }

    private String getData(String line) {
        String[] tokens = line.split("=");
        int length = tokens[1].length();
        return tokens[1].substring(6, length - 7);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Migrator mg = new Migrator();

        mg.migrate("post_tran.tbl", "post_tran_cust.tbl");
    }
}
```